# How can I pass form data to my controller and then store it to database ? laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi i am actually new in laravel , and learning , i have been assigned a task to do and i had been working a lot but i am really stuck i need some help ,  this is the Admin Dashboard in which i am trying to create a form which submit the values of the form shown in the picture , from the view to the route and controller where controller uses a create function to add all those values in the database mysql

The Codes for Home View :

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">

                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in') }} {{$user}} ..!
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{route('home.create')}}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                    @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                    @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                    @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Adduser') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The Code for My Route in web.php is here:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {



    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

route::get('/admin/user/roles',['middleware'=>['role','auth','web'],function(){

    return "Middleware role";
}]);


route::get('/home','AdminController@index');
//route::post('/home/{name}/email/password/confirmpassword','HomeController@create');
Route::post('home', 'HomeController@create')->name('home.create');
```

and here's the HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {



         return view('home');


    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please tell me where am i making mistake cuz i tried a lot of things but it never worked :( always giving error

Comment: what the error you got?

Comment: I think instead of `array` you need to pass [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) in function

Comment: @sta please check again I have posted the error as well , so sorry forgot earlier .

Comment: @RobinSingh i will be grateful if you could tell me how ?

Comment: @UmairAli instead of `protected function create(array $data)` try `protected function create(Request $data)` or also try to public your function if not working

Comment: @RobinSingh you are awesome sir , it worked !!! thanks .

Comment: one thing that bothers me is that it shows me the output

{"name":"22","email":"umairali25621@gmail.com","updated_at":"2021-02-08T07:33:33.000000Z","created_at":"2021-02-08T07:33:33.000000Z","id":5}

how can i avoid that and return to dasboard

Comment: @UmairAli Intstead of `return User::create()` try `return redirect('your_url');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try public function to submit form data & use Request instead of array

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Laravel handles the parameters passed through GET or POST methods itself. 
   *. You must use `Illuminate/Http/Request` in your controller, exactly like the one used in `index` function. 
    You don't need to use `Request $request` in `index` if you're just showing the view.
   Instead you should use it in `create`. 
   And for using it:

```html
public function create(Request $request)
{
  $data = $request->validate([
    // validation rules
  ]);
  
  $user = User::create($data);
  
  // .. anything you want
}
```

Be aware you're still able to use each parameter with `$request->nameOfParameter`
Its name is the name that you passed through HTML form.
Hope to be useful.

Doc: [Laravel 8 Request Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)